# Fastest way to convert large Sympy expression to readable string

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I have a sympy script that I use to compute the dynamical model of a complex robot. At the end of the script, I would like to store the result in a readable format, in a file.

The symbolic calculus are relatively fast (~5 secondes) but the conversion from the internal format Sympy use to readable format takes an eternity.

Storing the expression using pickle is fast but unreadable, and generate a large file (269Kb).
I have tried using the Sympy printing functions but they all take an eternity (Longest run ~ 32 hours, not finished).

Example code :

```py
th1 = symbols('th1')
DV1 = sin(th1)
DV2 = cos(th1)
torques = DV1^2 + 2*DV2 # Computation, fast

torques_str = str(torques) # Conversion, extremely slow

with open('torques.txt', 'w') as f: # Save string
    print >> f, torques_str
```

What can I do to efficiently convert my Sympy expression in a readable format and store it in a file?

Comment: What's the length of the `torques_str`?  I wonder whether the 'computation' step is really doing that, or is it just creating the expression?

Comment: It sounds like you do have a large expression. What does `torque.count_ops()` show? It shouldn't take 32 hours though so there may be an inefficient algorithm in the printing code somewhere. I recommend opening an issue on github if you can find a simple way to reproduce the problem.